# Globe brightness in series circuit

Tags: dc, series, brightness

So in a simple DC series circuit, why do some globes shine more brightly than others? And which ones are the brightest? Obviously each consumes a certain amount of voltage but I don't think the brightness decreases through each lamp- more like the middle is the brightest (or something crazy like that, or I could be wrong about literally everything).

I'd appreciate any clarification.

Thanks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4sU7e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: By 'globe', do you mean 'lamp' ?

Comment: Have you built this circuit and noticed brightness differences, or is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: This is an imprecise/subjective question which can only have a guesswork or broad answer.

Comment: "identical" is just theoretically ideal assumption. In real life, these bulbs may not be 100% identical after production. They may have slightly different resistances due to various physical factors.

Comment: @TonyM - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-globe

Comment: @brhans, yes, I know. OP switches terms and the drawing shows 'lamp', none of which keeps it clear for all readers here.

Comment: "globe" is kind of a Victorian-era term for lamp bulb. Not common, though it may be in use in some parts of the world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lights are identical within a small tolerance, one has a very slightly higher resistance than the others.

With the same current in each, (as must be true in a series circuit) the higher resistance one will dissipate more power and heat up more : this further increases its resistance, heating it up further, increasing its resistance. Finally it may have twice or more the resistance of the other relatively cool bulbs, dissipating twice the power and glowing much brighter.

Measure the resistance of each bulb when cold.
Measure the voltage across each bulb when hot.
Compare the ratio of these voltages to the ratio of resistances when cold.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the lights are identical, they should all be equally bright. Because the resistances are the same, the voltage is divided equally between them, each getting 1/3 of the battery voltage.

If they are not the same brightness, then they cannot be identical. Either one is somehow more efficient than the others, or one is higher wattage (lower resistance).

Comment: This does not address or answer the OPs question. It just explains what 'identical' means here and the OP already understands that.